# Rails, rspec: using "send()" to dynamically generate capybara URLs for controller specs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metaprogramming, rspec3

Inside a controller spec for a #show action:

```
resource_name = "adoption_transfer_type"

it "returns a single resource" do
  resource = create(resource_name.to_sym)

  # Works
  xhr :get, api_v1_lookups_adoption_transfer_type_path(resource.id)

  # Does not work
  xhr :get, send("api_v1_lookups_#{resource_name}_path(#{resource.id})")
end
```

It results in the following error:

```
Failure/Error: xhr :get, send("api_v1_lookups_adoption_transfer_type_path(#{resource.id})")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `api_v1_lookups_adoption_transfer_type_path(66)'
```

It looks like `send(...)` is converting it to a string literal instead of executing it as Ruby code, but I thought that was the purpose of the `send(...)` method.

The broader picture is I'm using a single spec file to generate the specs for several lookup resources, since they are all the same and there's no reason to manage 10+ files when I can do it all in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the string interpolates to `api_v1_lookups_adoption_transfer_type_path(2)` which means you're trying to call some method by that name. Instead you want:

```
send("api_v1_lookups_#{resource_name}_path", resource.id)
```

This is how you pass arguments to a send call, also i'd get into the habit of using `public_send` =)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I appreciate your explanation; it makes sense now that I look at it.